# Unable to Build iOS Package

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am using Trigger.IO to build an iOS package for the first time and receiving:

Failed to parse individual architecture

No clue what it's talking about though.  Any insights? I've just created a signing cert and perhaps that's the issue?  The full error:

```
[ERROR] Failed when running java: 2014-09-12 16:10:07.471 INFO: Loading certificate and private key
2014-09-12 16:10:07.643 INFO: Found certificate alias: iPhone Distribution: G Carlin (PBMQA8AJN4)
2014-09-12 16:10:07.644 INFO: Deleting existing CodeResources file
2014-09-12 16:10:07.645 INFO: Generating resources file
2014-09-12 16:10:07.956 INFO: Writing resources file
2014-09-12 16:10:07.974 INFO: Resources file complete
2014-09-12 16:10:07.975 INFO: Found fat binary, extracting separate architectures
2014-09-12 16:10:07.983 INFO: Extracted 2 architectures, processing each one individually
2014-09-12 16:10:07.983 INFO: Processing architecture
2014-09-12 16:10:07.987 INFO: Found valid binary
2014-09-12 16:10:07.987 INFO: Removing existing code signature
2014-09-12 16:10:08.267 INFO: Architecture processed
2014-09-12 16:10:08.267 INFO: Processing architecture
2014-09-12 16:10:08.268 SEVERE: Failed to parse individual architecture.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Trigger.io changelog:

> iOS code signing does not work under Windows and Linux due to changes
>   in Apple's codesigning requirements. We're working on updating our
>   cross-platform codesigning tools but if you need to submit your app in
>   a hurry you should probably ask a friend if you can borrow their Mac!

If you don't need iOS 8 support you can carry on working with platform version 2.1.9 as code signing still works with it on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Good to know that Windows will not work with cross-platform builds for the moment.  So I switched over to my Mac. Error is now: "Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: /Users/kleina1/Documents/forge-workspace/tfc/development/ios/device-ios.app: replacing existing signature
/Users/kleina1/Documents/forge-workspace/tfc/development/ios/device-ios.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable".  I'll research but any ideas?

Comment: Had to add Xcode command line tools to get it to work.  I think I've got it building now.

Comment: Issue is resolved in v2.2.3, code signing should work under Linux and Windows again.